# Calculation resulted in $NaN

Tags: javascript

I think my issues is with parsing the "$" but I'm not sure how to go about resolving it. Here is the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ottster/7oe9oy4a/

could this "$" cause the issues with $NaN

```
$total = "$" + ($amount * $product);
```

Comment: `$amount * $product` is returning `NaN` which you then convert to a string and concatenate to `$NaN` with `"$" + (NaN)`

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question. Don't make us go to another site, which could disappear, to view a complete code example.

Comment: No. But not converting strings to numbers could--but we have no idea what those variables *contain*.

Comment: You're issue is on this line `$product = $("value");`. That doesnt return a number. It returns an array. $product is also globally defined which isnt good.

Comment: Seems like you just made a typo and meant this: https://jsfiddle.net/7oe9oy4a/1/ where I updated that line to be `$product = $("#product").val();` and I removed concatenating the dollar sign to $amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you multiply String with Number

```
$amount = "$" + $("#slider").slider("value");   //here result is in String format, like "$10"
$product = $("value"); //also there is no such path
$total = "$" + ($amount * $product); // "$10"*20 - results to "$Nan"
```

So working code should be something like this:

```
$amount = $("#slider").slider("value");
$product = $("#product").val();
$total = "$" + ($amount * $product);
....
$('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> $' + $amount + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the NaN issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is $amount is a string = "$somevalue"

```
 $amount = "$" + $("#slider").slider("value");
```

And the $product is a jQuery array`$product = $("value");`

And you're trying to multiply the array (object) and the string, so you'll get NAN